# ArrayField missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, django

I have imported the following header file

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
```

Used the following in the model

```
question_array = ArrayField(models.IntegerField, blank=True,)
```

i get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py3.5.egg\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py3.5.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py3.5.egg\django\apps\config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python35-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\cstrom\comp\models.py", line 24, in <module>
    class User(models.Model):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\base.py", line 157, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\base.py", line 316, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 689, in contribute_to_class
    self.set_attributes_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py3.5.egg\django\contrib\postgres\fields\array.py", line 75, in set_attributes_from_name
    self.base_field.set_attributes_from_name(name)
TypeError: set_attributes_from_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Comment: ^Very good point, whilst the answers try to address resolving the error you're getting. The variable name you're giving it suggests that this should probably be a `ForeignKey` or other relationship

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield)

You still need to fully define the field inside the array field

```
question_array = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True), blank=True,)
```

Answer (score 4):

`models.IntegerField` is a function not a property, so you will be required to call it like a function. `()` at the end

```
question_array = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(blank=True), blank=True,)
```

Read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/).

Comment: It's a class actually, `blank=True` is passed to the constructor.